# Multiply columns of a matrix with 2d matrix slices of a 3d matrix in MatLab

Tags: matlab, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

Basically, I want to perform the following computation:

```
    G is m x n x k
    S is n x k

    Answer=zeros(m,d)
    for Index=1:k
        Answer(:,Index)=G(:,:,Index)*S(:,Index)
    end
```

So, answer is a matrix, whose columns are the result of multiplying each layer of a 3d matrix with a column of another matrix.

This really seems like a straightforward type of operation, and I was hoping to find out if there is a native or vectorized (or at least >> faster) way of performing this type of computation in Matlab.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using [mtimesx from the Matlab File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support). It's the best (fast/efficient) tool I've found so far to do this sort of n-dimensional array multiplication, since it uses `mex` . I *think* you could also use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/techdoc/ref/bsxfun.html), but my Matlab-fu is not enough for this sort of thing.

You have `m x n x k` and `m x k` and want to produce a `n x k`.

`mtimesx` multiplies inputs like `i x j x k` and `j x r x k` to produce `i x r x k`.

To put your problem in `mtimesx` form, let `G` be `m x n x k`, and expand `S` to be `n x 1 x k`. Then `mtimesx(G,S)` would be `m x 1 x k`, which could then be flattened down to `m x k`.

```
m=3; 
n=4; 
k=2;
G=rand(m,n,k);
S=rand(n,k);

% reshape S
S2=reshape(S,n,1,k);

% do multiplication and flatten mx1xk to mxk
Ans_mtimesx = reshape(mtimesx(G,S2),m,k)

% try loop method to compare
Answer=zeros(m,k);
for Index=1:k
    Answer(:,Index)=G(:,:,Index)*S(:,Index);
end

% compare
norm(Ans_mtimesx-Answer)
% returns 0.
```

So if you wanted a one-liner, you could do:

```
Ans = reshape(mtimesx(G,reshape(S,n,1,k)),m,k)
```

By the way, if you post your question on the [Matlab Newsreader forums](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/) there'll be plenty of gurus who compete to give you answers more elegant or efficient than mine!

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it will do what I want. I'll check back in when I can test it.

Comment: what if m varies in each k slice?

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15248109/how-to-do-m-n-k-n-k-m-k-in-matlab

Answer (score 1):

Here is the bsxfun() version. If A is an m-by-n matrix and x is an n-by-1 vector
then A*x can be computed as

```
sum(bsxfun(@times, A, x'), 2)
```

The operation permute(S, [3 1 2]) will take the columns of S and distribute them along the 3rd dimension as rows. The [3 1 2] is a permutation of the dimensions of S.

Thus sum(bsxfun(@times, G, permute(S, [3 1 2])), 2) achieves the answer but
leaves the result in the 3rd dimension. In order to get it in the form you want
another permute is required.

```
permute(sum(bsxfun(@times, G, permute(S, [3 1 2])), 2), [1 3 2])
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is to represent your 3d matrix as a 2d block diagonal matrix, with each layer being a diagonal block. The 2d matrix in this case should be represented as a vector containing the stacked columns. if the matrix is large, declare it as a sparse matrix.

Comment: That will work, I'm not totally convinced it will help speed though. I'll try it out later.