# How to do (m,n,k) * (n,k) = (m,k) in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vectorization, matrix-multiplication

I have found this relevant question:
[Multiply columns of a matrix with 2d matrix slices of a 3d matrix in MatLab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8698456/multiply-columns-of-a-matrix-with-2d-matrix-slices-of-a-3d-matrix-in-matlab)

I have the same problem but in my case `m` can vary for each slice. Is there a way to do that with [mtimesx](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support) ? Because `m` varies, my 3d tensor is stored as a list of cells, each containing a matrix. Also my 2d matrix is rather a list of cells each containing a vector.

Is there a way I can do this multiplication without a for loop?

Comment: I'm confused as to which letter represents what. So you have a `k` element cell array containing matrices of various sizes, and an equally long cell array of vectors whose length matches the respective matrix' size along the second dimension?

Answer (score 1):

Since your data is already stored in cellarrays, you can use [`cellfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html)

```
res = cellfun( @(x,y) x*y, mnkCell, nkCell, 'UniformOutput', false );
```